# Catching exceptions on fwrite and fread on a file in USB and USB removed while process is progressing

Tags: visual-c++, windows-ce

i am writing to a file in USB and while in progress i removed the USB. In the code i am using fwrite to write to the file. i put a try{} catch(...){} block to handle the exception. Exception wasn't getting caught.

i have a requirement to upgrade the firware from USB. so i am using fread to read a chunk of data from the file and sending the command to the module. While the reading is in progress, i removed the USB. Same try{} catch(...){} block to handle the exception. but the exception is not gettign caught

Thanks
Ajai

Comment: have you tried using __try/__except instead?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link to know about exceptions in WinCE and how to track the exceptions.

[Windows CE: Finding the cause of a Data Abort](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/05/19/windows-ce--finding-the-cause-of-a-data-abort.aspx)